# Listener for timestamp with firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm using firebase with react native and I wanna show a notification for the clients when the current time is 8pm, is there a way to listen to the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule cloud functions with Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Modified example from docs:

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('0 20 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun(context => {
    console.log('This will be run every day at 20:00 Eastern!');
    return null;
  });
```

Use this tool to generate crontab syntax for whatever time/interval you want: https://crontab.guru/